# Why does my *scratch* buffer save data in aquamacs emacs?

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

In regular emacs my understanding was that if you killed the scratch buffer, when you switched back to it it would be empty, or when you closed and restarted emacs, it would be empty. With Aquamacs, it seems to preserve the buffer contents. Why might this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Aquamacs changes documentation says:

> The *scratch* buffer is now persistent
>   across sessions. It is saved to an
>   internal file, but File / Save As (or
>   Apple-Shift-S or C-x C-w) still allow
>   users to save the file elsewhere. (To
>   switch this off, customize the
>   `aquamacs-scratch-file' variable to
>   nil.)

http://braeburn.aquamacs.org/code/master/aquamacs/doc/AquamacsHelp/node42.html